# Building v8 without JIT

Tags: javascript, jit, v8

I would like to run some tests on v8 with and without JIT to compare
performances.
I know JIT will improve my average speed performance, but it would be
nice for me to have some actual more detailed tests results as I want to work with mobile platforms.

I haven't found how to enable or disable JIT like it exists on Squirrelfish (cf. ENABLE_JIT in JavaScriptCore/wtf/Platform.h).

Does somebody knows how to do that with v8?

Thanks.

Alexandre

Answer (score 14):

For those who may be interested I got the following answer from Søren Gjesse on v8-users google groups.

---

Hi,
It is not possible to disable dynamically generated code in V8. Unlike other
JavaScript engines V8 does not have an interpreter mode - it always
generates native code.

One exception is the RegExp engine which have an interpreter and native code
version. The compile time define V8_NATIVE_REGEXP enables generating native
code for RegExp processing.

Regards,
Søren

---

Answer (score 2):

On a 32 bit little endian platform you can build with the ARM simulator.  This is a testing feature and performance will be terrible, but it does work and involves no direct execution of JITed code.  Use the --simulator=arm option on the scons or test.py command line.